# Where do Predators keep their mines?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-vs.-predator, predator, predator-series

In the 2010 video game [Aliens vs. Predator](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Aliens_vs._Predator_(2010_video_game)) (or *AVP 3*), when you have the the mines as the Predator, where would they be stored? Do they go on the belt? Because that’s the only place I think it could be.

Comment: Q. Where does Napoleon keep his armies? A. Up his sleevies.

Answer (score 5):

After reviewing a video footage of the Predator emplacing mines, along with images of the predator sprites used in the game the only conclusion I can draw is that he's pulling them out of his "[Hyperspace **Arse**nal](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HyperspaceArsenal)".

[image: close up on the Predator]

There is **literally no place** he could hold a dozen mines, each the size of a can of tuna unless his rectum works in a *dramatically different way* to that of a human.

Comment: Alright thanks dude, i was thinking that they could be stored under the top part or the leg armour or in one of those pockets on the Preds belt

Comment: -1 for IT'S A TVTROPES TRAP!

Comment: @dvk - http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TVTropesWillRuinYourLife

Comment: Is that supposed to be for me?

Comment: @Thecrazybull - I was trying to trick DVK into losing another hour of his life...

Comment: @Richard - Achievement Unlocked - Trap DVK in the maze of links